# Atom editor is not executing programs

Tags: atom-editor

Hello my atom software is not executing programs . i would love to know how i can solve this problem

```
::When i execute i am given the following error
[          ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:606:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:683:10)

    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:196:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:622:3][1]
```

Comment: Atom has no functionality to execute anything. If you are using third-party packages to do so, please tell us which one you're using and the exact name of the command that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a program in Atom I would first try downloading and installing the [Script package.](https://atom.io/packages/script) After installing this package, open your file and go to the packages menu. You'll see the newly installed script. Select this to run your script. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do all your lib/*.js files have at the top this line?

```
'use babel';
```